Excel: Applying SUBTOTAL() within VSTACK() (for a Sum of a Filtered Column)
INTRODUCTION / DESIRED RESULT
I am trying to create a table that automatically updates and that can be filtered. In this table, I want to add a dynamically column total at the end of the 'time difference' column using VSTACK() and SUBTOTAL(109; ...).
This is the intended formula:
=VSTACK( C2#-D2#, SUBTOTAL(109, C2#-D2#)).
.
PROBLEM DESCRIPTION
When I try to use SUBTOTAL() within the VSTACK() function, I get the follwoing error message.
Example table applying the SUBTOTAL function and error message
I am German and thus my Excel is in German language...
VSTAPELN() = VSTACK()
SUMME() = SUM()
TEILERGEBNIS(109; ...) = SUBTOTAL(109, ...)
The error message translates to:

There's a problem with this formula.
Not trying to type a forumal?
When the first charcter is an equal(=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula.
you type: =1=1, cell shows : 2
To get around this, type an apostrphe (') firts:
you type: '=1=1, cell shows: =1+1

.
TRIED APPROACH
To rule out the possibilities of an input or formula mistake, I tried simply replaced the SUBTOTAL(109, ...) with the SUM() function inside the VSTACK() formular.
The SUM() function works (inside VSTACK())
The SUBTOTAL() does not work (inside VSTACK())
Unfortunately, I cannot use the SUM(...) function because it includes the filtered/hidden rows.
Example table applying the SUM function
.
QUESTIONS / REQUEST FOR HELP
Does the SUBTOTAL() function simply not work within VSTACK() or am I applying it wrong?
Could someone help me with applying the SUBTOTAL() function within VSTACK(), or suggest an alternative (formular) approach?
Many thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have adapted the problem description to make it easier to understand.  #push-topic-up
